# Dimension of SO(5)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm trying to calculate the dimension of the irreducible representation of the SO(5) group with maximum weight equal to $2\lambda_1$. However I must be missing something because according to the books the group has dimension 10 and rank 2, and my calculations are giving dimension 12.

$dim\,D^{\lambda}=\frac{\underset{\alpha>0}{\prod}(\lambda+\delta)\cdot\alpha}{\underset{\alpha>0}{\prod}\delta\cdot\alpha}$, where $\delta=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$ and $\alpha^{2}=2$

$\delta\,\cdot\,\alpha_{1}=1  \quad\quad\quad   \delta\,\cdot\,\alpha_{2}=1  \quad\quad\quad   \delta\,\cdot\,\alpha_{3}=2  \quad\quad\quad   \delta\,\cdot\,\alpha_{4}=2$

and

$\alpha_{1}\,\cdot\,2\lambda_{1}=2  \quad\quad\quad \alpha_{2}\,\cdot\,2\lambda_{1}=0  \quad\quad\quad \alpha_{3}\,\cdot\,2\lambda_{1}=2  \quad\quad\quad \alpha_{4}\,\cdot\,2\lambda_{1}=2 \quad\quad\quad  $

applying in the formula:

$dim\,D^{2\lambda_1}=\frac{((2+1)*(1+0)*(2+2)*(2+2)}{(1)*(1)*(2)*(2)}=\frac{48}{4}=12$

Where am I going wrong ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which one do you think $\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$ are? It's just that they have the same inner product with $2\lambda_1$, so I cannot tell them apart. First off though, it should be $1+1$ in the numerator, not $2+1$.

Comment: Hi David, well the $\alpha_4$ would be $2\lambda_1$ and α3 = α2+α1....
in fact I think I was wrong when it came to the topic, because $\alpha_{1}\,\cdot\,2\lambda_{1}=2$ right? so it's still 2 + 1, or am I wrong?

Comment: So the norm of $\alpha_4=2\lambda_1$ is $\sqrt2$, which I agree with. Now how can the inner product of $\alpha_4$ and $\alpha_1$ be the same as that of $\alpha_4$ and itself?

Comment: I did not understand α4⋅2λ1=2 would be zero?  remember that we can normalize $\alpha^2=2$

Comment: What do you think $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ is? All other formulae should follow from this.

Comment: These are the simple roots right?, but I still don't understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: Right, well I get $10$ when I work it out. Just answer what you think $(\alpha_1,\alpha_1)$, $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and $(\alpha_2,\alpha_2)$ are, and then what you think $\delta$ is. Then it's just addition. I personally think the answers are $1$, $-1$, $2$ and $2\alpha_1+3\alpha_2/2$ respectively.

Comment: And the eight values I get to be $1/2$, $1$, $3/2$, $2$, $1$, $0$, $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Perfect, I understood my mistake! 10 points is not enough .... I'm not familiar with the compensation system .... how did you deliver your points?